# Problems in csv import

Tags: python, csv

I am quite new to python programming. I don't know what the problem is.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
pd.read_csv('C:/Python34/libs/kospi.csv')
```

I'd like to import csv file in a specific folder, but only to fail.
What's the problem? How can I designate specific file path?

```
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
----> 4 pd.read_csv('C:/Python34/libs/kospi.csv')
--> 452         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
--> 234     parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
--> 542         self._make_engine(self.engine)
--> 679             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
-> 1041         self._reader = _parser.TextReader(src, **kwds)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb3 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific than *"fail"*?

Comment: Describe your problem. Any error output?

Comment: It may be that you need a windows path ('C:\\Python34\\libs\\kospi.csv'), but I don't have a windows machine lying around to check.

Comment: Thanks llogiq, but your suggestion does not work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the file path but with the encoding of the file you're trying to open:

```
pd.read_csv('C:/Python34/libs/kospi.csv', encoding="...")
```

You need to [set the `encoding` parameter](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-read-csv-table) to the encoding used by your file - must be something other than UTF-8.